# Crosscompile go(lang) app with docker for alpine linux (musl) aarch64 with native libs so CGO enabled

Tags: docker, cross-compilation, alpine-linux, arm64, golang

### Background

I'm writing an open-source GTK go app subsonic API client which:

- targets on first place mobile friendly Linux like [postmarketOS](https://postmarketos.org/) (alpine linux), [Mobian](https://mobian-project.org/) (debian)
- in future will be also extended to desktop Linux, Windows and Mac OS but not Android or iOS as they already have one.
- needs to be available at least on `aarch64` and `x86_64`
- depends on native libs like `portaudio`, `libasound`, `libopus`
- so it needs `CGO` to be enabled

I haven't published app yet as I self-host my git and I have to do some additional config. It won't be available until late october 2021.

App successfully compiles (on host) and runs on my main PC which is x86_64 fedora.

App successfully compiles (on docker) and runs on aarch64 **glibc** distros like Mobian

This is Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.17-bullseye
LABEL os=linux
LABEL arch=arm64
ENV GOOS=linux
ENV GOARCH=arm64
ENV CGO_ENABLED=1
ENV CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
ENV PATH="/go/bin/${GOOS}_${GOARCH}:${PATH}"
ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
# install build & runtime dependencies
RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64 
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y 
RUN apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
        protobuf-compiler \
        upx \
        gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu \
        libc6-dev-arm64-cross \
        pkg-config \
        libasound2-dev:arm64 \
        libgtk-3-dev:arm64 \
        libcairo2-dev:arm64 \
        libglib2.0-dev:arm64 \
        libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:arm64 \
        libsamplerate0:arm64 \
        libsamplerate0-dev:arm64 \
        libopusfile0:arm64 \
        libopusfile-dev:arm64 \
        libopus0:arm64 \
        libopus-dev:arm64 \
        libportaudio2:arm64 \
        portaudio19-dev:arm64 
# install build dependencies (code generators)
RUN go get github.com/hajimehoshi/oto \
    && go get github.com/faiface/beep \
    && go get github.com/faiface/beep/flac \
    && go get github.com/faiface/beep/speaker \
    && go get github.com/faiface/beep/mp3 \
    && go get github.com/faiface/beep/vorbis \
    && go get github.com/faiface/beep/wav\
    && go get github.com/gotk3/gotk3 \
    && go get github.com/delucks/go-subsonic \
    && go get github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp \
    && go get github.com/zalando/go-keyring \
    && go get github.com/emirpasic/gods/lists/ \
    && go get github.com/emirpasic/gods/lists/arraylist \
```

### Problems

1. I can't run Mobian working binary on postmarketOS as alpine linux uses musl instead. `file` output is: `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, (...) for GNU/Linux 3.7.0. not stripped`.
2. I haven't manged to use musl toolchain in docker debian as it is 32 binary executable and image is 64 bit.
3. I couldn't find anything about multiarch in alpine so probably I can't use docker image goalng:1.17-alpine on x86_64 (I'd have also to find native libs packaged)

I wish it's just problem with my config, if it's possible I'd love solution with docker as I'd like to use CI/CD in future.

### Resources, ideas, workarounds

- I have raspberry pi with debian installed with some services. I could use with  native musl toolchain and debian aarch64 docker container but it's not handy in production pipeline. Also, I haven't tried this.

### Good to read

1. [Crosscompile CGO projects (also with docker)](https://dh1tw.de/2019/12/cross-compiling-golang-cgo-projects/)
2. [Crosscompile with cross-platform musl toolchains](https://ariya.io/2020/06/cross-compiling-with-musl-toolchains)
3. [Related stackoverflow thread about alpine linux and go binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279253/go-compiled-binary-wont-run-in-an-alpine-docker-container-on-ubuntu-host)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I needed to build a static Go binary with cgo that would eventually run in an *alpine* container with *arm64* architecture, but had to be built in a *golang:alpine* container with *x86_64* architecture (I didn't have control over the CI/CD runner architecture).

I got it to work by downloading a cross-compiler (CC) and specifying that it be used during the Go build.

Here is an example of downloading/extracting the CC in the container user's home directory and using it in a go build based out of `/usr/src/example` that produces an executable named *exampleApp*.

```bash
wget -P ~ https://musl.cc/aarch64-linux-musl-cross.tgz
tar -xvf ~/aarch64-linux-musl-cross.tgz -C ~
cd /usr/src/example
GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=~/aarch64-linux-musl-cross/bin/aarch64-linux-musl-gcc go build -o exampleApp -a -ldflags=-extldflags=-static .
```

Running `file` on the `exe` output verified it was statically linked for
aarch64. I was then able to run it in an arm64 alpine container elsewhere.

Comment: musl.cc seems to have rather outdated packages mostly from Nov 2021. Only some recent mingw packages.